# Remove part of string by pattern

Tags: php, string

I have a string. I need to remove `render_dynamic_content(`, leave the text  and then remove next `)` from the string. The text inside the pattern can be different. 
Example:

```
some ( text {{ render_dynamic_content(dynamic_html.POS_A_IMG) }} another ) text {{ render_dynamic_content(dynamic_html.POS_B_IMG) }}
```

Expected result should be:

```
some ( text {{ dynamic_html.POS_A_IMG }} another ) text {{ dynamic_html.POS_B_IMG }}
```

I'm trying:

```
$string = 'some ( text {{ render_dynamic_content(dynamic_html.POS_A_IMG) }} another ) text {{ render_dynamic_content(dynamic_html.POS_B_IMG) }}';
$content = preg_replace('/render_dynamic_content([\s\S]+?)/', '', $string);
```

The result is:

```
some ( text {{ dynamic_html.POS_A_IMG) }} another ) text {{ dynamic_html.POS_B_IMG) }}
```

I need to remove `)` after `dynamic_html.POS_A_IMG` and `dynamic_html.POS_B_IMG`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but you need to include (and escape) the parenthesis in your pattern, and then put the captured part (the part you want to keep) in the replacement instead of an empty string.

```
$string = 'some ( text {{ render_dynamic_content(dynamic_html.POS_A_IMG) }} another ) text {{ render_dynamic_content(dynamic_html.POS_B_IMG) }}';
$content = preg_replace('/render_dynamic_content\(([\s\S]+?)\)/', '\1', $string);

echo $content;
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8160bf1ae2bf88f9aa1ea2fddfe5f4627429d8b6)

NOTE: Some other pattern may or may not be more efficient.  For the purpose of this answer, I'm not going to try to optimize it.